# Getting Value in Jsp using UseBean

Tags: jsp, servlets, liferay

Friends I am sending My List from Action class, here is the code

//Code of my Action class

```
List matchUsersInTracker = new ArrayList<User>();

DynamicQuery userTrackerquery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(User.class, PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader())
    .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("userId").in(DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(UserTracker.class, PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader())
    .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("userId"))));

matchUsersInTracker = UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(userTrackerquery);

//Pass this entire List of user 
if(matchUsersInTracker!=null)
{
    actionRequest.setAttribute("match_base_Users", matchUsersInTracker);
}
```

//code in My Jsp -------

Now in Jsp I am using useBean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="match_base_Users" class="java.util.ArrayList"  scope="request">
</jsp:useBean>
```

It gives me `ClassCastException`, now converting each and every element to user class one by one in for loop isn't the feasible way.

Increases loading time of my jsp.

So any guesses how can I send a User List from `ActionClass` to Jsp

I also referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263642/jsp-usebean-with-hashmap) but was not able to come out with a resolution.

I just want to display data in jsp

Comment: What do you want to do with the list, can you write the code after `<jsp:useBean>` to explain? By the way is `ArrayList` a `Java Bean` **:-)** ?

Comment: please have a look i edited post hope it makes clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `<jsp:useBean>` at all if you're already using a MVC framework which manages the beans in the desired scope. The `<jsp:useBean>` is only useful if you aren't using a MVC framework which managed the beans by itself.

Get rid of it and just access it by `${match_base_Users}` directly.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, can you suggest me a few links that can Optimise my MVC coding pattern.